# How to combine SCNRenderer with an existing MTLCommandBuffer?

Tags: swift, opengl-es, scenekit, vuforia, metal

I successfully integrated the [Vuforia SDK Image Target Tracking feature](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Image-Target-Guide) into an iOS project by combining the OpenGL context (`EAGLContext`) that the SDK provides, with an instance of SceneKit's `SCNRenderer`. That allowed me to leverage the simplicity of the SceneKit's 3D API and at the same time benefiting from Vuforia's high precision image detection. Now, I'd like to do the same by replacing OpenGL with Metal.

**Some background story**

I was able to draw SceneKit objects on top of the live video texture drawn by Vuforia using **OpenGL** without major problems.

Here's the simplified setup I used with **OpenGL**:

```
func configureRenderer(for context: EAGLContext) {
    self.renderer = SCNRenderer(context: context, options: nil)
    self.scene = SCNScene()
    renderer.scene = scene

    // other scenekit setup
}

func render() {
    // manipulate scenekit nodes

    renderer.render(atTime: CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent())
}
```

**Apple deprecates OpenGL on iOS 12**

Since [Apple announced that it is deprecating OpenGL on iOS 12](https://developer.apple.com/ios/whats-new/), I figured it would be a good idea to try to migrate this project to use the `Metal` instead of `OpenGL`.

That should be simple in theory as Vuforia supports Metal out of the box. However, when trying to integrate it, I hit the wall.

**The question**

**The view seems to ever only render results of the SceneKit renderer, or the textures encoded by Vuforia, but never both at the same time. It depends what is encoded first. What do I have to do to blend both results togeter?**

Here's the problematic setup in a nutshell:

```
func configureRenderer(for device: MTLDevice) {
    let renderer = SCNRenderer(device: device, options: nil)
    self.scene = SCNScene()
    renderer.scene = scene

    // other scenekit setup
}

func render(viewport: CGRect, commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, drawable: CAMetalDrawable) {
    // manipulate scenekit nodes

    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)

    renderer!.render(withViewport: viewport, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, passDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
}
```

I tried calling `render` either after `encoder.endEncoding` or before the `commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor` :

```
metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
metalCommandQueue = [metalDevice newCommandQueue];
id<MTLCommandBuffer>commandBuffer = [metalCommandQueue commandBuffer];

//// -----> call the `render(viewport:commandBuffer:drawable) here <------- \\\\

id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> encoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];

// calls to encoder to render textures from Vuforia

[encoder endEncoding];

//// -----> or here <------- \\\\

[commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
[commandBuffer commit];
```

In either case, I only see results of `SCNRenderer` **OR** results of the `encoder`, but never both in the same view.

It seems to me as if the encoding pass above, and the `SCNRenderer.render`, are overwriting each other's buffers.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems to me that you definitely want to draw the Vuforia content first. When you draw SceneKit second, what color are the portions of the frame that SceneKit isn't drawing to? Also, have you tried capturing the GPU frame in Xcode and double-checking that the render pass properties are correct? That will tell you a lot more than what we can infer from these code snippets.

Comment: Have you tried rendering the SceneKit scene offscreen to a separate texture, and then over-blending that texture with the vuforia results? Also, seconding the GPU frame capture idea.

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer.
I am rendering **scnrenderer** after **endEncoding**, but I'm creating a new descriptor.

```
    // Pass Metal context data to Vuforia Engine (we may have changed the encoder since
    // calling Vuforia::Renderer::begin)
    finishRender(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(drawable!.texture).toOpaque()), UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passRetained(encoder!).toOpaque()))
    
    // ========== Finish Metal rendering ==========
    encoder?.endEncoding()
    
    // Commit the rendering commands
    // Command completed handler
    commandBuffer?.addCompletedHandler { _ in self.mCommandExecutingSemaphore.signal()}
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let newDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    
    // Draw to the drawable's texture
    newDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable?.texture

    // Store the data in the texture when rendering is complete
    newDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreAction.store
    // Use textureDepth for depth operations.
    newDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = mDepthTexture;
    renderer?.render(atTime: 0, viewport: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height), commandBuffer: commandBuffer!, passDescriptor: newDescriptor)
    
    // Present the drawable when the command buffer has been executed (Metal
    // calls to CoreAnimation to tell it to put the texture on the display when
    // the rendering is complete)
    commandBuffer?.present(drawable!)
    
    // Commit the command buffer for execution as soon as possible
    commandBuffer?.commit()
```